# CakePHP 3 : display data from other model and pass parameter in url from action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm working on a project using CakePHP 3.x.

I have `UserAddress`, `ServiceRequests`, `Service` models.

There is a button on `service/view/$id` which when clicked will ask user to select address from `service-requests/serviceArea` which has a list of addresses added by user. `service-requests/serviceArea` view will contain a `select` button which when clicked will call `add` action in `ServiceRequests` controller with passing two parameters `serviceId` and `userAddressId`

This is the serviceArea function created by me.

```
public function serviceArea($id = null)
    {
        public $uses = array('UserAddress');
        $service = $id;
        $query = $userAddresses->find('all')
          ->where(['UserAddresses.user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);



        $this->set(compact('userAddresses'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['userAddresses']);
    }
```

How to display the address and also pass the `$service` parameter to the `serviceArea` view.

I am new to CakePHP, so if you think question is incomplete any edit to it will be appreciated instead of down-voting.

Thank You.

---

> Edit 2

Thank for your answer @jazzcat

After changing my code according to yours and visiting `http://domain.com/service-requests/service-area/$id`. It is showing error as
`Record not found in table "service_requests"`

and pointing to the `ServiceRequestsController` on line no **33**

The `ServiceRequestController` as containing line no 33 is

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * ServiceRequests Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ServiceRequestsTable $ServiceRequests
 */
class ServiceRequestsController extends AppController
{

    /**
    * isAuthorized method
    *
    */
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
      $action = $this->request->params['action'];

      // The add and index actions are always allowed.
      if(in_array($action, ['index', 'add', 'serviceRequests'])) {
        return true;
      }
      // All other actions require an id.
      if (empty($this->request->params['pass'][0])) {
        return false;
      }

      // Check that the service request belongs to the current user.
      $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
      $serviceRequest = $this->ServiceRequests->get($id);  // line : 33
      if($serviceRequest->user_id == $user['id']) {
        return true;
      }
      return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }

        /* Other actions */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

Just added the `serviceArea` action name in the `isAuthorized` method

```
if(in_array($action, ['index', 'add', 'serviceArea'])) {
        return true;
}
```

and it's working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot wrong with your code. Please read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html)

Is the table named user_addresses or user_address ?
You seem to mix the both.

The following would be the correct way to do it assuming your table is named **user_addresses**

```
public function serviceArea($id = null)
{
        $this->loadModel('UserAddresses');

        $userAddresses = $this->UserAddresses->find('all')
            ->where(['UserAddresses.user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);

        // If you want to filter on the serviceArea ID aswell
        if($id)
            $userAddresses->andWhere(['id' => $id]);

        // Setting SerivceArea ID to compact makes it available in view.
        $serviceAreaId = $id;

        $this->set(compact('userAddresses', 'serviceAreaId'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['userAddresses']);
}
```

This snippet:

```
$id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
$serviceRequest = $this->ServiceRequests->get($id);  // line : 33
```

Just checks if the first parameter passed to the method exists in ServiceRequests.

(That parameter could be anything, you have to keep that in mind when creating all your methods in that controller, that is to say the least.. bad)

I'm **assuming** that the service_requests table is associated with the users table and an user_id column exists in the service_requests table.

If that is the case this should work:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
      $action = $this->request->params['action'];

      // The add and index actions are always allowed.
      if(in_array($action, ['index', 'add'])) {
        return true;
      }

      // Is not authorized if an argument is not passed to the method.
      // Don't know why you'd want this , but sure.
      if (empty($this->request->params['pass'][0])) {
        return false;
      }

      // Check that the service request belongs to the current user.
      $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
      $serviceRequest = $this->ServiceRequests->find()->where(['ServiceRequests.user_id' => $user_id])->first();
      if(!empty($serviceRequest)) {
        return true;
      }
      return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my `edit 2` of the question.

Comment: im guessing the parameter sent with the url is not '$id' , actually an UUID ?

Comment: Since you're taking the first argument of each method in that controller and passing them to $this->ServiceRequests->get($id); it's not going to work for methods that take something other than service_requests->id as argument. That's why the record isn't found, since you're passing the id of user_addesses.

Comment: can you suggest any solution to this ?

Comment: Now, it is saying `You are not authorized to access that location.` after updating according to your code. I think you are searching for record in ServiceRequests model. But the record will be added to the table later. Table might be empty or user might not have placed any request.

Comment: If your record will be added to the table later, why are you trying to find a record associated with the user in the service_requests table in the first place?

Comment: I am not trying to find a record associated with the user in the `service_requests` table. I'm trying to find all records from `user_addresses` table associated with the user and list them on `service_area.ctp` view from which user will select one address and then two parameters will pass to add method (`user_address_id` and the `service_id`) to place a service request on user's address chosen by him. currently `service_id` is passing to `serviceArea` method which will carry forward to the `add` method with `user_address_id`

Comment: Then you should uncomment isAuthorized or set it to always return true, and try to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: I also need isAuthorized because user's address will only show if he is login else he will be redirected to login page before place service request. I have got somewhere to pass value as `http://website.com/service-requests/service-area?q=$id` will it work. I tried it but it is redirecting to home page `http://website.com`